# Line Paths Alternative?

Tags: animation

Is there an easier to work with way of moving an object around a scene than with line paths or normal keyframes?

I’ve been having lots of trouble with line paths as I can’t figure out how to make objects continue on doing other animation once they’ve completed the line paths.

Also regular keyframes are hard to nail the proper speed and is also difficult making a curved turn.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parenting your object to the path, you can use a "follow path" constraint.

Set the offset value to the frame number you want your object to follow the path and in the same frame set a keyframe to put the object in the 0,0,0 location. Push the button animate path in the constraint tab, and set the timing of the path in the curve's property panel, "path animation" tab.

A the end of the animation set some keyframes to animate the influence of the follow path constraint, so you will be able to freely animate your object.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! When I animate the influence, the object moves back to its original spot, how can I keep it at the end of the line

Comment: Let's say your path animation goes from frame 1 to 101: on frame 1 you will set a keyframe influence 1.0 and a loc 0,0,0 for the object. At frame 101 the same (both influence and loc). At frame 102 first set a "visual location" keyframe for the object, then an influence of zero for the constraint. After a first run the animation will correctly fix the loc at the end of the curve.

Comment: For rotation should I do the same?

Comment: Set an appropriate rot keyframe at frame 1 and copy it on 101. In the constraint you can check the "follow curve" parameter, to have your object rotating with the curve and having the possibility to control the tilt of your object adjusting the "tilt" value of every control point of the curve (you can find the tilt value selecting a control point in edit mode and checking the transform values in the "N" properties panel). Then, at the end, set a visual rot keyframe at 102.